# GROUP BY with Key:Value filters for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by, having

Given a table with following schema:

| RecordId | ProcessId | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80830F00-379C-11EA-96B7-372060281AFC | 1 | 4.2 |
| 80830F00-379C-11EA-96B7-372060281AFC | 2 | 445588662211448 |
| 80830F00-379C-11EA-96B7-372060281AFC | 7 | 1 |
| 791F6D30-379C-11EA-96B7-372060281AFC | 1 | 3.3 |
| 791F6D30-379C-11EA-96B7-372060281AFC | 2 | 999999999999999 |
| 791F6D30-379C-11EA-96B7-372060281AFC | 7 | 2 |

So the `RecordId` represents some grouping key and each `ProcessId` has its `Data`.

Now I have a filter which looks like this:

```
filter: [
    { "1": "3.3" },
    { "2": "999999999999999" }
]
```

So the `key` is `ProcessId` and `value` is `Data`.

#### Question

How can I get all `RecordId`s which satisfies query meaning that each group (grouped by `RecordId`) should contain specific processes with specific data.

I believe it should be used like this:

```
SELECT RecordId
FROM [SomeTable]
GROUP BY RecordId
HAVING --- the row with ProcessId = 1 AND Data = '3.3'
    AND --- the row with ProcessId = 2 AND Data = '999999999999999'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `having` with `case`:

```
SELECT RecordId
FROM [SomeTable]
GROUP BY RecordId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ProcessId = 1 AND Data = '3.3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN ProcessId = 2 AND Data = '999999999999999' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.